# Where in this photo can I find archaea?

Tags: archaea

This photo is from [Guide to the Six Kingdoms of Life](https://www.thoughtco.com/six-kingdoms-of-life-373414) under Archaebacteria:

[image: photo of "Archaebacteria"; there is an orange/yellow flow (maybe sulphur) into a river with visible steam, there's white powdery substance (likely snow) coating the land, and there's a black gooey-looking region; there's some grass on the banks of the river]

It's not obvious to me where I can find [archaea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archaea) in this photo, although the website seems to indicate it's clear.

**Question**: Where in this photo can I find archaea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably the yellow bacterial mats, which are rich in life. The mats are a stratified ecology which varies with distance from the surface, so they are rich in many species of algea, procarote and eukariote. In Yellowstone,  the bacterial mats can range in color including brown, green, yellow and orange. They are different to precipitated minerals.

You can say "The photographer contains archaea"! So, no need to search very far.

Here is a pic of an bacterial mat habitat: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0717345817300738

You can see in some videos. Ideally we would have a a biology video demonstrating the stuff at Yellowstone to show if it's squishy, slimy, spongey, has growth rings, colord layers, cross sections... although it's only [tourist videos for the moment](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=yellowstone%20bacterial%20mat).